ida versus idapro tags ... the synonym should be the exact inverse, because it's not strictly synonymous
The irritating thing about it is that apparently Igor was the one to introduce the synonym. As he points out in this comment to another meta question:

Actually, the official name of the program (since a few years ago) is just "IDA". "IDA Professional" is what was previously called "IDA Pro Advanced".

Considering there is IDA Professional, IDA Starter and a freeware version it would make more sense to call all of them "IDA" (ida) instead of "IDA Pro" (idapro) which refers to a single edition out of three possibilities. In short: ida is a superset of idapro and should be the one to use, unless we want to add other tags for the starter and freeware editions of IDA.
I know this is probably not going to be popular with the moderators, perhaps not with Igor either, but as a matter of fact it would be:

more correct
shorter
more inclusive


I had a look at the IDA website, and the software comes in three versions as stated in the question, freeware, IDA Starter and IDA Professsional. IDA seems to be the correct tag that encompasses all these. Hence, ida is now the master tag. idapro is the synonym.
I havent retagged the idapro questions as of now.

thanks for the effort!
